# Linux output to be displayed

Tags: linux

I have a shell script which outputs some user reports on linux server.
However the user is not havng access to the server and he wants to view the report files on a browser.
Is that possible? How can i do that?
I am totally new to this, So please help me where and how to start on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using those steps:

1. Install web server on the linux
2. Start the web server
3. Run your script and redirect the report to be written in documents
   directory of web server
4. Change permissions (in case of need) to your report to make it
   possible your web server to read the report
5. Provide the URL of the generated tile

Comment: I would just add that for such basic use u can write(google) basic python server, because on NIX you must have python by default and for showing only one file you most probably don't want to install software, so you could run your own python 5-liner.

Comment: Right, @Drako, if OP have python experience :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov don't really need python experience just googling skills :) it's 5 lines of code or less :) I could post them here but it's better if he finds that way better understands what he need and does it himself :)